# How consecutive bit-fields are converted to variable when casting

Tags: c, casting, structure, data-conversion, bit-fields

I would like to use flags in some structure, let say:

```
struct {
    flag1:1;
    flag2:1;
    flag3:1;
    flag4:1;
}Flags;
```

Flags 3 and 4 describe mode of my target project works in now.  I would like to convert the flags into a number to read what has been set in the flag3 and flag4.
What I do is:

```
uint8_t mode;
mode = ( ((uint8_t)Flags.flag4 << 1) | (uint8_t)Flags.flag3) );
```

What surprises me it works this way:

if flag4==1 and flag3==1 'mode' is 3

if flag4==1 and flag3==0 'mode' is 2
etc.

My question is: why? I did it with the hope it works but I don't know why.

I work in Atollic for STM32 code.

Comment: Are you asking us to explain your own code? No offense intended. It's just a question.

Comment: How can flag3 contain 2 when it is on one bit?

Comment: @Broman I know what I wrote, I just don't know why it happens.

Comment: @MrPromethee it's typo, should be 0

Comment: Ok, I will add some explanation:


flag4=1 and flag3=1 then the structure looks like this:

1100
if I do flag4<<1 , cast both to uint8_t and perform bitwise 'or' I should get:
10100

Can somebody explain me how the bitfields are interpreted when casting to other type?

Comment: If you knew what you wrote then why not post that code instead? Since this struct isn't valid C.

Comment: You are not casting. Avery field has a separate value. I your case 0 or -1.

Answer (score 1):

Because flag4 and flag3 will be interpreted as digits in a binary number. flag4 will be the most significant.

`Flags.flag4 << 1` will bitshift flag4 to the left, so if flag4 is 1, the result of this is 10. Then we perform a logical or with flag3. If flag3 is 1, this will yield 11, which is 3 in binary.

Here is a little loop that might explain it. Let's say that we have 8 flags in an array, `int flags[8]`. Now we want to compress these into a `uint8_t flagfield`. That can be done with this loop:

```
flagfield=0;
for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    flagfield |= (uint8_t)(flags[i] << i);
```

`flagfield` will now contain all flags. If you wish you can interpret it as a regular integer.

Comment: So my flag4 is treated as: 0001 when I cast it to uint8_t? Even if it is surrounded by other fields?

Answer (score 0):

When `flag4` is 1 and `flag3` is 1, `flag4 << 1` is 10 (2 in decimal) because you shift 1 to the left. With `|` you add `flag3` which isn't shifted so you have 11 (3 in decimal).

When `flag3` is 0 it does the same thing but the result is 10 (2 in decimal) because `flag3` is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Lets disect the code:

mode = ( ((uint8_t)Flags.flag4 << 1) | (uint8_t)Flags.flag3) );

First:

```
(uint8_t)Flags.flag4
(uint8_t)Flags.flag3
```

Flags.flag4 and Flags.flag3 are cast to uint8_t. This part is important. While Flags.flag4 and Flags.flag3 only has one bit the cast turns that into a full 8 bit.

Next:

```
((uint8_t)Flags.flag4 << 1)
```

This shifts the value of flag4 1 bit to the left. It's the same as `x * 2`. Remember the cast turned this into a full 8 bit. So the shift does not overflow. flag4 can only be 0 or 1 so after the shift this is 0 or 2.

Last the two values are ored together. That gives a result of 0-3 depending on the values of flag3 and flag4.

Note an alternative way to write this, although architecture/ABI specific is to use

```
struct {
    uint8_t flag1:1;
    uint8_t flag2:1;
    union {
        struct {
            uint8_t flag3:1;
            uint8_t flag4:1;
        };
        uint8_t flag34:2;
    };
} Flags;
```

The order flag3 and flag4 are in memory is sepcified in the calling conventions of the architecture/ABI so the flag34 isn't as portable. You might have to reoerde the flags to get the optimal result (shortest/fastest assembly).

Answer (score 0):

`mode = ( ((uint8_t)Flags.flag4 << 1) | (uint8_t)Flags.flag3) );`

when:

> if flag4==1 and flag3==0 'mode' is 2

explanation:

```
Flags.flag4 == 1
1 << 1 == 2
2 | 0 == 2
```

> if flag4==1 and flag3==1 'mode' is 3

```
Flags.flag4 == 1
1 << 1 == 2
2 | 1 == 3
```

You need a good beginners C book